# How to find out browser's version in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I want to find out how many users are using IE8 in my asp.net mvc project,is there a simple way? Now I have got the browser's user agent, like "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3)",so, how to find out if the browser is IE8? Thanks!

Comment: You could use Google Analytics - which would tell you a lot more than just browser version.

Comment: In ASP.NET, look at the Request.UserAgent property - but I suggest looking at your logs directly.